# Messed up Log4J configuration in webapp

Tags: tomcat, log4j

My webapp running in Tomcat 7 is repeating the same log message 6 more times. For example:

```
[INFO] 1
29042 [http-nio-8443-exec-4] INFO com.lni.exchange.healthvault.ParseMeasurement  - 1
29042 [http-nio-8443-exec-4] INFO com.lni.exchange.healthvault.ParseMeasurement  - 1
29042 [http-nio-8443-exec-4] INFO com.lni.exchange.healthvault.ParseMeasurement  - 1
29042 [http-nio-8443-exec-4] INFO com.lni.exchange.healthvault.ParseMeasurement  - 1
29042 [http-nio-8443-exec-4] INFO com.lni.exchange.healthvault.ParseMeasurement  - 1
29042 [http-nio-8443-exec-4] INFO com.lni.exchange.healthvault.ParseMeasurement  - 1
```

The expected written output is just the first line ([INFO] 1) but then I get 6 repeats of that message. Does anyone have any idea why the message repeats so many times? Probably messed up my log4j properties which has always been a little confusing to me.

I have an Axis2 1.6.2 deployment using Spring that is receiving data and sending it to HealthVault.

Here is the log4j properties file:

```
# Set root category priority to INFO and its only appender to CONSOLE.
#log4j.rootCategory=INFO, CONSOLE
log4j.rootCategory=INFO, CONSOLE, LOGFILE

# Set the enterprise logger priority to FATAL
log4j.logger.org.apache.axis2.enterprise=FATAL
log4j.logger.de.hunsicker.jalopy.io=FATAL
log4j.logger.httpclient.wire.header=FATAL
log4j.logger.org.apache.commons.httpclient=FATAL

# CONSOLE is set to be a ConsoleAppender using a PatternLayout.
log4j.appender.CONSOLE=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout.ConversionPattern=[%p] %m%n

# LOGFILE is set to be a File appender using a PatternLayout.
log4j.appender.LOGFILE=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.LOGFILE.File=axis2.log
log4j.appender.LOGFILE.Append=true
log4j.appender.LOGFILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.LOGFILE.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n
```

Comment: When I have similar problems with logging lines appearing multiple times, I usually change my logging properties to the minimal logging configuration (only one appender, only root logger) and then enrich this configuration step by step until I figured out where the error was.

Comment: Okay, I didn't mean to 'blame' Tomcat for this but as stated log4j and my lack of understanding of how log4j works. The properties file appears everywhere. In this case I have a single axis2 deployment. There is a log4j properties file in the WEB_INF/classes directory that influences the output level (debug or info, etc.) but I don't see why it (by itself) causes repeats.

Comment: could you post this log4j.properies file here?

Comment: I added it to the original message. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is not Tomcat, this is some app deployed to it. Ask the app dev.

Comment: It's the same log message that appears multiple times in the log. This is typically an error in the log4j settings. The app dev can only help if it's the app that brought this misconfigured log4j settings with it.

Comment: Tomcat does not use Log4J nor is the `logging.properties` misconfigured if no one has tampered with.

Comment: Since the author wrote "Probably messed up my log4j properties which has always been a little confusing to me." I would not blame tomcat for the misconfiguration but the author of the question. My point was: it is not necessarily the developer of the app but the person who did the configuration

Comment: Then his question is simply wrong. Tomcat does not repeat anything because Tomcat does not log that.

Answer (score 0):

Likely log4j is your culprit:

http://www.jajakarta.org/log4j/jakarta-log4j-1.1.3/docs/TROUBLESHOOT.html#duplicates